# Relationship between price and quantity in R

Tags: r, modeling

I tried to figure out how I can analyze this project. To find out how to analyze relationships between prices and quantities. I think with only two variables you can't build models.

For example,  one pencil company sells
100 pencils for 10 dollars,  200 for \$15, 300 for \$30, 400 for \$35, etc/

How can you analyse this relationship in R?

Comment: This is a poor question for this forum.  Go to a statistics or math forum.

Comment: once you have more specific questions, stackoverflow is all yours, but this is much too broad.. start with creating a `data.frame` (or better, a `data.table`) `df` with fields `price` and `quantity`, then look at `plot(df$price,df$quantity)`. that should get you started.

Comment: Now that your question is on CrossValidated, it should not be about a specific program (R) but about statistics.  I am not sure, here, if your emphasis is on R or statistics.

Comment: actually on both.

Comment: I see several choices: 1) use $lm$ function to fit linear model, 2) use $nls$ package if you have non-linear model; 3) if you have differential equation model you can use $deSolve$ package + Monte-Carlo methods to estimate the parameters. In addition it would be nice if you share the data, which are under analysis as the method of choice heavily dependend on dependence character. What you showed is not reflecting the problem you're solving.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the relationship is linear, you could do:

```
quantity <- c(100,200,300,400)
price <- c(10,15,30,35)
plot(quantity~price)
fit <- lm(quantity~price)
abline(fit)
summary(fit)
```

Comment: thanks, i actually built this already, but too many pricing do not make sense , so the model is not statistically significant

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical question in microeconomics. You are trying to estimate [a demand function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_curve). Paired values of prices and quantities are absolutely sufficient to do that. Usually there is the basic assumption of linear relationships. You do not show us your data so maybe a nonlinear model would also be appropriate.

You find a very basic introduction to this topic [here](http://www.econ.jku.at/members/WinterEbmer/files/Teaching/managerial/ws14-15/estimating.pdf).

Comment: So in case test of linearity is tells us that there is no linear relationship, we need to use non-linear regression? If yes, can you name any such non-linear regression technique which is appropriate for calculating price elasticity?

Answer (score 0):

HOSS_JFL is right, but it should be highlighted that it is far from clear what exactly you are measuring if you regress prices on quantities: is it a supply or a demand function or a mixture of both? If you can't tell what drives the variation in prices, you can't tell which side of the market you explain.
This would be a classic example for endogeneity problem which requires instrumental variables or system of equation estimation. See the systemfit package for detail. They even discuss the case of supply and demand functions in the introduction of the methods.

Comment: thanks for your reply.   If it is supply and demand I found similar example.
But this is like finding errors.  I know linear regression should work.
but there are many errors on pricing. I want to know if you can see from standard deviation.  for example. $10 for 100, 15 for 150, 20 for (500),
30 for 300, $40 for 350.  some pricing just do not make sense.  building linear model won't be significant because too many errors.

Comment: It is still completely unclear what type of data you have in addition. You must verify that you can attribute the variation of prices/quantities respectively to the shocks of a specific side of the market. This is why you need instrumental variables. Take your numbers from above: the first two entries look like a supply function: quantity increases with price. The third entry could still be part of the supply function, but it would be very non-linear. The latter entries are not in line.
So maybe you have shifts in your demand function and in the costs of the supplier you have to control for?

Comment: As an example: Let's say 20 for 500 is the coincidence of high demand and very high costs, while 30 for 300 and 40 for 350 is a coincidence of very high demand and low costs. You see what I mean? From the prices and quantities alone, you cannot deduce anything about the underlying forces. You have to use instrumental variables for the underlying shocks. Maybe then it makes all sense?
Honestly, this is a classic question of applied microeconomics / econometrics, so learn the basics! Plus: take a look on the documentation of the systemfit package. (google: >R systemfit vignette<)